# Deny insert when column value is empty

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have my php code that will hold and insert date to mysql:

from an input textbox

```
$id2 = $_POST['id'];
```

Random Number Generator
How can I generate it always on 5 digit?

```
$random = rand();
```

Insert code:

```
$sql3="Insert into warranty(serial_no,a_id)
values ('$random','$id2')";
$result3=mysql_query($sql3);
```

How can I deny insert when $id2 doesn't have a value?

Comment: You are vulnerable to SQL injection and are [using a deprecated library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

Just use `empty()` function to determine, if given variable has value or not ([manual page](http://php.net/empty)). Like this:

```
if (!empty($id2))
{
   $sql3="Insert into warranty(serial_no,a_id) values ('$random','$id2')";
   $result3=mysql_query($sql3);
}
```

But passing `$_POST` value directly to SQL query is huge* security issue (**SQL Injection** to be clear), os use at least [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string):

```
$sql3="Insert into warranty(serial_no,a_id) values ('$random','" . mysql_real_escape_string($id2) . "')";
```

For more info about this, read [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

**EDIT:** At first, I miss your second question, so moved from comments - to generate 5 digits random number, use simple:

```
$fiveDigitsRand = rand(10000, 99999);
```

Comment: how can I generate random numbers always on 5 digits sir?

Comment: Simply with `rand(10000, 99999);`

Answer (score 1):

put below code and remove existing code.You don't have need of $id2 variable if you are getting value using $_POST method. You can do it directly by following code.

```
$random = rand();

if(isset($_POST['id']))
{   
$sql3="Insert into warranty(serial_no,a_id)
values ('$random','".$_POST['id']."')";
$result3=mysql_query($sql3);
}
else
{
echo "No ID Found"; //you can do any action here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$random = rand(10000,99999);

if(!empty(trim($id2)))

```
{
  $sql3="Insert into warranty(serial_no,a_id) values ('$random','$id2')";
 $result3=mysql_query($sql3);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(isset($id2))
{
$sql3="Insert into warranty(serial_no,a_id)
values ('$random','$id2')";
$result3=mysql_query($sql3);
}
```

Comment: iseet() tells him only if given variable is set, not if has some value. Empty is better here.